# Remove specific record from Sitecore WFFM using C#

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

Hi I am trying to remove a specific record from sitecore WFFM. For example, delete the entry that contain certain email address but I cant find a way to do it. I just able to delete all of the record from the form.

Is there any way to remove just a specific entry using C#?
I tried to replace the FormItemId with the entry id but not working or I am in the wrong direction?

```
Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataManager.DeleteForms(new Sitecore.Data.ID(frm.FormItemId), frm.StorageName);
```

Thank you!